# how to update the grandchildren values of object array react

Tags: reactjs

After retrieving data from the database, I am about to update the values of a field when a user clicks a button. In this case, I need to update the value of flag_used.

```
// App.ts

interface UserSponsorType {
  id: number,
  value: string,
  flag_used?: boolean
}

interface SponsorType{
  user_sponsors: Array<UserSponsorType>
  id: number
}

export function App() {
   const selected<Array<SponsorType>> = data; // from the database

   const onHandlerClick = () => {
     selected.user_sponsors.map(userSponsor => {
        // update the value of flag_used here
        // Note that flag_used is optional
     });
     console.log(selected);
   }

   return <Button onClick={onHandlerClick}>Click</Button>
}
```

How can I update the value of flag_used of first/nearest object where flag_used is not equal to true?

Example data:

```
data = [
   {
     id: 1,
     user_sponsors: [
        { id: 1, value: "test", flag_used: false},
        { id: 2, value: "test"},
     ]
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     user_sponsors: [
        { id: 3, value: "test", flag_used: true},
        { id: 4, value: "test", flag_used: false},
     ]
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     user_sponsors: [
        { id: 5, value: "test", flag_used: true},
        { id: 6, value: "test", flag_used: true},
        { id: 7, value: "test", flag_used: false},
        { id: 8, value: "test", flag_used: false},
        { id: 9, value: "test", flag_used: false},
     ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
const onHandlerClick = () => {
    let flagFirstItem = true;
    const newSelected = selected.user_sponsors.map(userSponsor => {
        if (userSponsor.flag_used === false && flagFirstItem) {
            flagFirstItem = false;
            return {
                ...userSponsor,
                flag_used: true,
            }
        }
        return userSponsor
    });
    console.log(newSelected);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added sample data and I think, this won't work on 
`{ id: 7, value: "test", flag_used: false},`

Comment: @smzapp oh, i've updated my answer, can you verify again?